# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> EDIT START

So I found the issue with my code. It was the following line

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['faq_submit'])) {
```

I am not sure whats wrong with this line? Why wouldn't it be working properly?

> EDIT END

For some reason my prepared statement isn't working. Also it doesn't seem to be displaying any errors in the error log. Now I am probably just doing something wrong there but I am sure someone here could spot something wrong I did haha... I tried fixing it in a couple different ways and was just unsuccessful so asking here for help is always a good resort!

Here is the my php code for adding a question

```
// Required Configuration
include_once('required.php');

// double check page was accessed via submit button
if(isset($_REQUEST['faq_submit'])) {
    // get data that sent from form
    $topic=trim($_REQUEST['faq_topic']);
    $detail=trim($_REQUEST['faq_detail']);
    $name=trim($_REQUEST['faq_name']);
    $email=trim($_REQUEST['faq_email']);

    // check if all forms are filled out
    if(!empty($topic) && !empty($detail) && !empty($name) && !empty($email)) {
        // Validate Email
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Prepared Insert Statement
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO forum_question (`topic`, `detail`, `name`, `email`, `datetime`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

            // Bind Variables To Values
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $topic, $detail, $name, $email, $datetime);

            // Execute Prepared Statement
            $stmt->execute();

            // Print Results
            $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>You <strong>successfully</strong> submited a question to the FAQ bored.</div>';
            print($html);

            // Close Connections and Statement
            $stmt->close(); // Statement
            $mysqli->close(); // MySQLi
        } else {
            // Email Validation Failed
            $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>Your <strong>email</strong> was invalid.</div>';
            print($html);
        }
    } else {
        // If the required items were not filled out print the following
        $html = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>All</strong> forms are required.</div>';
        print($html);
    }
}
```

Here is that required.php file although I have removed some of the login info.

```
$datetime=date("m/d/y h:i"); // Format Date And Time

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

// Check Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Where is '$datetime' ? also it's int or string?

Comment: Enable error handling. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your page.

Comment: I added it to the top and no errors get displayed

Comment: What is the output when you run this?

Comment: Ok, I tested your code and was successful. Check to see that you've chose the right types for your columns, the right DB, the right table, etc., that your form elements are named and with no typos. `faq_email` is not the same as `Faq_Email` and submit button is good. @kmgilbert100 Plus, if you're using any JS/Ajax, check that too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- hey I got it working, I had to remove if(isset($_REQUEST['faq_submit'])) { idk whats wrong with that code though?

Comment: It's most likely that either your form element isn't named as in `name="faq_submit"`, or isn't a proper submit button, or that your form is using a GET, or that you may need to change it to `if(isset($_POST['faq_submit']))` it's hard to say without seeing the form you're using. It could be a number of things, or mix of. It's always best to post full code, it takes all the guesswork out of things ;-) show me the form and I will tell you right away.

Comment: Well, if you won't or can't post your form, I can't help you figure out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking if any statement errors are being thrown? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: I haven no errors get displayed

Comment: try wrapping your prepare() in an if, to narrow it down. i.e. $stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { ... }

Comment: Have a look at example #1 on http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php